# How to increase framerate?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

With the fact that AC4 is very graphics-intensive, most people get a terribly low FPS while playing it. For me, the maximum I have gotten is 24, and my average is 15-20, even while playing on the lowest graphics settings.

Are any file modifications, third-party programs, etc. available to increase overall FPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you tell more about your system that you are trying to run the game on?

- OS
- Graphics
- Ram
- Processor
- Hard drive

A simple way to increase you're gaming experience is to get a ssd /shhd hard drive. A lot of laptops run integrated graphics on the processor those systems aren't meant for gaming.

To answer your question better: I tried a lot of third-party programs to increase my experience but all of them where bad.

The general tip for increasing FPS is to have less background processes running on you system. Look if you have a bunch of different programs/processes running in Task Manager that you don't have use for.

Comment: Um, Windows 7, 6GB RAM, Intel CORE i7, 1TB Hard Drive, AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series graphics card

Comment: Since you have a 6700M I assume it's a laptop. Do you know what speed the Hard drive is running at? if it's 5400 that could be a reason why you are experiencing the low fps. You can look in to upgrading to a ssd and if you want to have you storage space not limited you can replace the CD-reader with a Hard-Drive bay. But in general I'm sorry to say that most new high-end graphics games are to heavy for laptops(there are of course laptops that can handle it)

Comment: Not really sure about the speed, but anyway, thanks!

Comment: I'll wait a day or so. o_O

Comment: Almost none of this is useful information.

Comment: To that question i was just trying to give assistance. Just share General Knowledge :) @kotekzot